# How do I call didEndEditing?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitextfield

I'm doing form validation on my iPhone app. I want to call the didEndEditing method on my button submit. How do I do this?

**Here is my code**

This is the method

```
-(void)didEndEditing:(UITextField*)textField;
{
   // Do Something!
}
```

Here I'm calling the method

```
-(IBAction)btnSelected:(id)sender {
   UIBarButtonItem *bbi = (UIBarButtonItem *) sender;

   if (bbi.tag == 1) {

       [self didEndEditing]; // How do I call this method?
    }
 }
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: Notice that your calling `didEndEditing` without an argument, i am surprised that you don't get a unrecognized selector exception. But as I answered below you should not call this method yourself.

Comment: Yes, and it works great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume your refering to `textViewDidEndEditing:`? you should not call that method yourself it will be called when the text field is not the first responder anymore. From the API documentation:

> Implementation of this method is optional. A text view sends this message to its delegate after it closes out any pending edits and resigns its first responder status. You can use this method to tear down any data structures or change any state information that you set when editing began.

If you want validate I suggest that you refactor out the validation code and call it from both `textViewDidEndEditing:` and submit.

You can loop thru all text fields like this:

```
for (UITextField *textField in [NSArray arrayWithObjects
                                self.textField1,
                                self.textField2,
                                nil]) {
   // validate textField
}
```

If you need different validation per field you could make a more complex data structure that includes validation block, regex etc for each field.

Comment: Well, I'm doing my form validation in textViewDidEndEditting. This will only work if the user click on the textField. What if the user not click on the textField and click on the submit? I want to validate all the fields that required on submit.

Comment: Ok. Could it work if you do validation in the same method as you submit? or refactor out he validation code an call it from both `textViewDidEndEditing` and the submit method.

Comment: Well textViewDidEndEditing method is useful to validate the user on the spot. I also wants to validate the user from submit as well, but on submit I want to validate all the fields at same time!

Comment: I think i would refactor out the validation code somehow and call it from both textViewDidEndEditing and submit. If you don't have a lot things to validate you could probably get away with validating all fields each time. Keep it simple, computers are fast.

Comment: Ok, is there any way to loop through all the textFields?

Comment: Yeah could probably loop through all views but i would suggest that you put them into an array then loop through them. I can update my answer them some code.

Answer (score 0):

You should just resignFirstResponder on the active textField:

```
-(IBAction)btnSelected:(id)sender {
   UIBarButtonItem *bbi = (UIBarButtonItem *) sender;

   if (bbi.tag == 1) {

       [self.myActiveTextField resignFirstResponder];
    }
 }
```

Then didEndEditing should get called on its own.

Comment: Could work if `resignFirstResponder` will trigger a call to `textViewDidEndEditing:` directly and not after returning the the main UI loop.

Comment: Well I did call [self.txtAddress resignFirstResponder]; this in my submit and it never went in to any textField methods!

Comment: Was not called at all? is the text view and or controller removed after you submit?

Comment: Are you sure that you have your view set up correctly as a UITextFieldDelegate? And have the delegate property of the field assigned correctly?

Comment: Good point, that's is weird, but you get calls when the user manually changes between fields?